# Multiple stylesheets for qt application

Tags: qt, stylesheet

Is it possible to have multiple stylesheets for a single qt application and select any of them as needed?

For instance, I would like to have different styles of push buttons within my application. I understand that normally you would have something like:

```
QPushButton { background-color: green; }
```

And then all your push buttons will have the green style as per the above line. However, I would like to have my stylesheet to look somehow like this:

```
QPushButton1 { background-color: blue; }
QPushButton2 { background-color: green; }
```

I may need to place several push buttons in my application and for each of those, I want to select either the QPushButton1 style or the QPushButton2 style.

Is this feasible to do within one or multiple stylesheets, so that I can use setStyleSheet() to enable my custom style?

Thanks!

Comment: If you set the styles heet on the application level, it would be global style sheet and every `QPushButton` is affected. Otherwise, you may set style sheet on each `QPushButton` individually to have different color styles.

Comment: In addition to Chernobyl's answer, I would like to suggest you read the stylesheet example within your Qt's installation folder (`/Examples/widgets/widgets/stylesheet`). It saves different style sheet as `.qss` files (just text format actually) and load the corresponding one when user choose the theme from combobox. You may combine Chernobyl's answer and Qt's stylesheet example to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use global stylesheet and set special settings to each special object name.

```
#QPushButton1 { background-color: blue; }
#QPushButton2 { background-color: green; }
```

But in this case you also need to set these object names in code. It can be done with:

```
ui->pushbutton1->setObjectName("QPushButton1");
ui->pushbutton2->setObjectName("QPushButton2");
```

It is also possible to set same object name to different widgets.

About changing `objectName`. When you change `objectName`, `Qt` will not re-apply `styleSheet` automatically (it was done for better performance), so you should do this manually. You can use `objectNameChanged` signal and re-apply `styleSheet` in corresponding slot or just something like:

```
ui->pushButton_2->setObjectName("QPushButton1");
qApp->setStyleSheet(qApp->styleSheet());//re-apply
```

Comment: Does this mean that I can have multiple pushbuttons with the same name: "QPushButton1"? In that case, I suppose the code can dynamically change the name of the pushbutton to change its style as well. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: @hANI 1. Yes, you can. 2. No, I added explanation  about this, so see my edited answer please.

Comment: Re changing object name - consider using [dynamic properties](https://wiki.qt.io/Dynamic_Properties_and_Stylesheets)